# Laravel 5.3 - Single Notification for User Collection (followers)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I have a single `notifiable` user, a single entry in the `notifications` table is inserted, along with a `mail`/`sms` sent which is perfectly working via channels.

The issue is when I have a `user` collection, a list of 1k users following me, and I post an update. Here is what happens when using the `Notifiable` trait as suggested for multi-user case:

1. 1k `mails`/`sms` sent (issue is not here)
2. 1k notification entries added to the DB's `notifications` table

It seems that adding 1k notifications to the DB's `notifications` table is not an optimal solution. Since the `toArray` data is the same, and everything else in the DB's `notifications` table is the same for 1k rows, with the **only** difference being the `notifiable_id` of the `user` `notifiable_type`.

An optimal solution out of the box would be:

1. Laravel would pick up the fact that it's an `array` `notifiable_type`
2. Save a **single** notification as `notifiable_type` `user_array` or `user` with `notifiable_id` 0 (zero would only be used to signify it's a multi notifiable user)
3. Create/Use another table `notifications_read` using the `notification_id` it just created as the `foreign_key` and insert 1k rows, of just these fields:

   `notification_id` `notifiable_id` `notifiable_type` `read_at`

I am hoping there is already a way to do this as I am at this point in my application and would love to use the built in Notifications and channels for this situation, as I am firing off `emails`/`sms` notifications, which is fine to repeat 1k times I think, but it's the entry of the same data into the database that is the problem that needs to be optimized.

Any thoughts/ideas how to proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Updated 2017-01-14: implemented more correct approach

**Quick example:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\SomethingCoolHappen;

Route::get('/step1', function () {
    // example - my followers
    $followers = App\User::all();

    // notify them
    Notification::send($followers, new SomethingCoolHappen(['arg1' => 1, 'arg2' => 2]));
});

Route::get('/step2', function () {
    // my follower
    $user = App\User::find(10);

    // check unread subnotifications
    foreach ($user->unreadSubnotifications as $subnotification) {
        var_dump($subnotification->notification->data);
        $subnotification->markAsRead();
    }
});
```

## How to make it work?

**Step 1** - migration - create table (subnotifications)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSubnotificationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subnotifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // primary key
            $table->increments('id')->primary();

            // notifications.id
            $table->uuid('notification_id');

            // notifiable_id and notifiable_type
            $table->morphs('notifiable');

            // follower - read_at
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('subnotifications');
    }
}
```

**Step 2** - let's create a model for new subnotifications table

```
<?php
// App\Notifications\Subnotification.php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection;

class Subnotification extends Model
{
    // we don't use created_at/updated_at
    public $timestamps = false;

    // nothing guarded - mass assigment allowed
    protected $guarded = [];

    // cast read_at as datetime
    protected $casts = [
        'read_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // set up relation to the parent notification
    public function notification()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DatabaseNotification::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the notifiable entity that the notification belongs to.
     */
    public function notifiable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Mark the subnotification as read.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function markAsRead()
    {
        if (is_null($this->read_at)) {
            $this->forceFill(['read_at' => $this->freshTimestamp()])->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3** - create a custom database notification channel
**Updated**: using static variable $map to keep first notification id and insert next notifications (with the same data) without creating a record in `notifications` table

```
<?php
// App\Channels\SubnotificationsChannel.php
namespace App\Channels;

use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SubnotificationsChannel
{
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed                                  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        static $map = [];

        $notificationId = $notification->id;

        // get notification data
        $data = $this->getData($notifiable, $notification);

        // calculate hash
        $hash = md5(json_encode($data));

        // if hash is not in map - create parent notification record
        if (!isset($map[$hash])) {
            // create original notification record with empty notifiable_id
            DatabaseNotification::create([
                'id'              => $notificationId,
                'type'            => get_class($notification),
                'notifiable_id'   => 0,
                'notifiable_type' => get_class($notifiable),
                'data'            => $data,
                'read_at'         => null,
            ]);

            $map[$hash] = $notificationId;
        } else {
            // otherwise use another/first notification id
            $notificationId = $map[$hash];
        }

        // create subnotification
        $notifiable->subnotifications()->create([
            'notification_id' => $notificationId,
            'read_at'         => null
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares data
     *
     * @param mixed                                  $notifiable
     * @param \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getData($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        return $notification->toArray($notifiable);
    }
}
```

**Step 4** - create a notification
**Updated**: now notification supports all channels, not only subnotifications

```
<?php
// App\Notifications\SomethingCoolHappen.php
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Channels\SubnotificationsChannel;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class SomethingCoolHappen extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        /**
         * THIS IS A GOOD PLACE FOR DETERMINING NECESSARY CHANNELS
         */
        $via = [];
        $via[] = SubnotificationsChannel::class;
        //$via[] = 'mail';
        return $via;
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

**Step 5** - helper trait for "followers"

```
<?php
// App\Notifications\HasSubnotifications.php
namespace App\Notifications;

trait HasSubnotifications
{
    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     */
    public function Subnotifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Subnotification::class, 'notifiable')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's read notifications.
     */
    public function readSubnotifications()
    {
        return $this->Subnotifications()
            ->whereNotNull('read_at');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's unread notifications.
     */
    public function unreadSubnotifications()
    {
        return $this->Subnotifications()
            ->whereNull('read_at');
    }
}
```

**Step 6** - update your Users model
**Updated**: no required **followers** method

```
namespace App;

use App\Notifications\HasSubnotifications;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Adding helpers to followers:
     *
     * $user->subnotifications - all subnotifications
     * $user->unreadSubnotifications - all unread subnotifications
     * $user->readSubnotifications - all read subnotifications
     */
    use HasSubnotifications;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works really well :) In step 4, I noticed the `toMail` is missing, I have some logic to find followers who want email, but then where do I put that logic? Since the example uses `$user->notify(new FollowersUpdate(...` it emails the `$user` when I put `toMail` in step 4, which is not what we want, as we want to email the followers, using some of the user details. I don't think putting it in `FollowerChannel` is correct since it handles the db tables entry? Any idea what's the correct location to implement?

Comment: @Wonka, As you did it previously. This approach only implements a custom database channel. You can try put your logic in FollowerChannel, but you're right - it is not a good place. In other words you have to use both `Notifications`: the original notification with sms/email and `FollowersUpdate` (to make subnotifications). I believe this is small enough price for your optimization.

Comment: @Wonka, i thought a bit more and came with more correct solution. Check it. Hope you'll find it more useful.

Comment: Thank you :) I used your updated example which allows multiple channels in a single notification, so for 100 followers, it adds 100 subnotifications but it also sends 100 emails, even if only 80 of the 100 want email, the other 20 get the email too. I opened this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643939/laravel-5-3-single-notification-file-for-different-user-collections But the offered solution is a foreach for each `$follower` to figure out their preference and loops over the notification, as opposed to sending the `$followers` and handling the prefs in the channels.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same single notification file with the passed `$followers` like in your example but also have the follower's mail preferences respected? I tried but wasn't able to get it to work...

Comment: @Wonka, yes, put required logic to Step4(Notification) `via` method. `$notifiable` is an eloquent model of your follower. Send email only to gmail users: `if (stripos($notifiable->email, '@gmail.com') !== false) $via[] = 'mail';`

Comment: When we are using this method is it possible for us to send a single email with all the specified users email in to filed of email. So if we need to inform 10 users with exact same information, instead of triggering 10 different emails, I need to send one email with 10 email ids in to, cc or bcc field.

Problem is when we send 10 emails one after other my transnational email provider return error "To many emails per second".

Comment: @karmendra You may just need a mail queue with throttling.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you are right i guess with the default `Notifiable` trait, you could create a [custom channel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#custom-channels).

You can check the `Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel` class for default creation and adopt it to a pivot-table one.

Hope this helps to create a new channel with a pivot table. Also, implement a `HasDatabasePivotNotifications` trait (or similar name) to your own `Notifiable` trait.

Comment: Do you mind sharing specific code to show how it would be possible to implement?

Comment: I added a 100 point bounty, since I am not 100% sure how to implement your solution. Can you flesh out your solution with sample code/pseudocode so I can implement it and report the results? A lot of people seem interested in this based on the upvotes :)

Comment: i will add till sunday (from now 3 days)

Comment: @Isfettcom Could you still show the implementation?