# Laravel 5.3 - Paginate notifications and subnotifications once?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-pagination

I can paginate notifications and subnotifications for user `notifiable_id` 5 individually without any issues. However, I am trying to have the results paginated together in one instance.

**1) DB table name/data**

`notifications`

[image]

`subnotifications`

[image]

**2) Pagination**

I can paginate each relation I have individually like this:

```
$notifs = $user->notifications()->where('type', 'UserWasFollowed')->paginate(10);
$subnotifications = $user->subnotifications()->with('notification')->paginate(10);
```

I need to be able to merge them to get back only one `paginate(10)` instance which has both notifications and subnotifications, so something like this for example (pseudocode):

```
$allNotifs = $user->(notifications()->where('type', 'UserWasFollowed'))
                  ->(subnotifications()->with('notification'))
                  ->paginate(10);
```

How can this be done with one pagination instance efficiently?

**Update 1:**

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;
    use HasSubnotifications;
}
```

**Subnotification Model**

```
class Subnotification extends Model {
    protected $table = 'subnotifications';

    // set up relation to the parent notification
    public function notification() {
        return $this->belongsTo(DatabaseNotification::class);
    }

    // Get the notifiable entity that the notification belongs to.
    public function notifiable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Query for user's:

a. Notifications of `UserWasFollowed` type from `notifications` table.

b. Subnotifications from `subnotifications` table with the related notification from `notifications` table.

```
$allNotifications = $user->subnotifications()->whereHas('notifications',function($query){
  $query->where('type', 'UserWasFollowed');
})->with('notification')->get();
```

Comment: Need to have a look at the HasSubnotifications trait

Comment: Step 5 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274477/laravel-5-3-single-notification-for-user-collection-followers

Comment: Replace 'notifications' with 'notification' in whereHas and with. I think it's just a naming issue, your relation in Subnotification is referred by notification method, and not notifications (typo). With and whereHas take the name of the method in arg

Comment: Replaced both 'notifications' to 'notification' instead, but returns an empty array `[]` even though all the data is there. Not sure why it's so complicated for such a simple joining of both notifications/subnotifications on the user model, but not issues at all when done individually.. Also, if you look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications under Accessing The Notifications, you'll see you call it as `notifications` off the user, we only do `notification` for the subnotification's related notification

Comment: It should be empty, judging from your screenshots, you have no notifications typed UserWasFollowed for the user, try another type. There's no row for notififiable_id 5 and notification_id 1

Comment: The very first notification is typed UserWasFollowed

Comment: But is there a row on subnotifications for notifiable 5 and notification 1 ? That was my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having not much information about the purpose of the subnotification table or what it does, you can try the following method :

```
public function your_method_name()
{
    /* IMPORTANT : Purpose of subnotification must be known to have a more structured query */
    $collection = $user->notifications()->where('type', 'UserWasFollowed')->get()->merge($user->subnotifications()->with('notification')->get());

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $perPage = 10;

    $currentPageData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();

    $paginatedFinalCollection = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageData, count($collection), $perPage);

    return dd($paginatedFinalCollection);
}
```

**Note** Talking about efficiency, the intent of `subnotification` must be known, why do you need it and how are you going to use the data retrieved by your second query. Having an answer to that might make a difference to `$collection`

---

**EDIT**
The simple way I can think of, is using a closure within your eager loading `with` 
Like so :

```
$sn = $user->subnotifications()->with(['notification'=>function($query){
      $query->where('type','UserWasFollowed');
}])->paginate(10);
```

You can learn more about it at [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) under **Constraining Eager Loads**

---

**UPDATE 2**
try this

```
$user->subnotifications()->whereHas('notifications',function($query){
    $query->where('notification_type','UserWasFollowed');
})->with('notifications')->get();
```

Using this with a similar setup worked fine for me.
*Note* Be sure to change the relations names to their proper ones if they don't match

**UPDATE 3**
When using your exact same setup for subnotifications provided in the related question, with the following queries :

`Notifications\TestNotification.php` is similar to the `SomethingCoolHappen.php` in the example.

The model, channel and migrations are the same. So you can use them as they are.
What I did to get what you wanted is the following :

```
Route::get('/step1', function () {
    // example - my followers
    $followers = App\User::first();
    // notify them
    $x = Notification::send($followers, new TestNotification(['arg1' => 1, 'arg2' => 2]));
    dd($x);
});

Route::get('/step2', function () {
    // my follower
    $user = App\User::find(1);

    $subnotifications = $user->subnotifications()->whereHas('notification',function($query){$query->where('type','App\Notifications\TestNotification');})->with('notification')->get();

//this gives you the subnotifications collection with the notification included
dd($subnotifications);

//get the notification linked to one entry of the collection
dd($subnotifications->first()->notification()->first());

});
```

Comment: Here is the subnotification intent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274477/laravel-5-3-single-notification-for-user-collection-followers What are your thoughts on the efficiency after knowing the intent? Would anything in the query change to make it the most efficient way for a single paginator?

Comment: Edited, test required

Comment: Tested out the edit, didn't work due to syntax error, since `with` should enclose its content in `[]` (same doc you linked). But even with the correct syntax, it only pulls out the `subnotifications` with the subnotifications table fields, and adds a key of `notification` which is `null` for the subnotifications (so notification data is not added). It also does not add the regular `notification` of `UserWasFollowed` at all in the query results. Any other ideas that may make it work?

Comment: Updated. Tested with a similar setup and worked for me. You can have access to the notification object normally.

Comment: Hmmm... I added an update to my question showing the code with the correct relations, but get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::notifications()` I am sure it's the whereHas `notifications` it is referring to in the error. I don't have that method on anything, since you just add notifiable on the user model, which I have and works individually when called `$user->notifications()->where('type', 'UserWasFollowed')->paginate(10);` but errors out when called using the updated syntax.

Comment: The ´notification' in whereHas and with refer to the relation method, replace it with what you have in your model

Comment: I updated with the question with the query/models. Notifiable on the User model is what allows us to do `$user->notifications()...` but it does not work from `whereHas` as it is added after the subnotifications. Changing the order doesn't work either. If you refer to 2) Pagination, I can paginate each relation I have individually like this: part, you will see they both access off the user model and work individually, but not when grouped like the update query syntax (as I think only one of them is able to pull of the data from the user model directly, but not when chained off the other model)

Comment: Try to add a method to your User model as subnotifications() which refers to the relationship with the subnotification table and with notifiable_id as the foreign key, switch between BelongsTo and HasMany for the sake of trial. **edit: looking the trait the model has that method**

Comment: Updated, test it

Comment: Hello again, still didn't work, but I created the exact setup very minimally. I put it in chat last night, let me know if you got it or when you're on again :)

Comment: check the discussion

Comment: I am in chat now